# Enable/disable commands after another command was executed

Tags: wpf, command

Heres a trick question. I have a number of commands that should be enabled/disabled after another command was called. Say, for example, I have Open, Save and Start commands. Save and Start commands should only be enable after Open command was successfully executed. And Open and Save commands must be disabled after Start command was called. Whats the best practice for this kind of situations?

Comment: In Prism, there's a class called 'CompositeCommand' which was designed for this sort of thing.  But if you are not using Prism, you can read the docs on this command and implement something similar.

Comment: Define "command".  Do you really mean method?  What do you mean trick question?

Comment: @Blam, I guessed that 'command' meant 'command' and 'trick' meant 'tricky'. :)

Comment: @Sheridan then your answer makes sense

Comment: @Blam, if only L.E.O. would come back to check on the question he asked, then maybe we'd find out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `ICommand` has a bool `CanExecute` element. The answer is to put your logic into these elements. I use a type of `RelayCommand` because I use MVVM, but this is irrelevant for this issue... the important thing is the bool parameter that specifies whether the `Command` can execute or not. I would do something like this:

```
private bool isOpen, hasStarted;

public ICommand Open
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => OpenCommand(), canExecute => 
        !hasStarted); }
}

private void OpenCommand()
{
    // do your stuff here
    isOpen = true;
}

public ICommand Save
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => SaveCommand(), canExecute => 
        isOpen && !hasStarted); }
}

private void SaveCommand()
{
    // do your stuff here
}

public ICommand Start
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => AudioTrack.RevertState(), canExecute => 
        isOpen); }
}

private void StartCommand()
{
    // do your stuff here
    hasStarted = true;
}
```

Clearly, you'll need to set the `hasStarted` and `isOpen` variables back to false again at some stage to re-enable that functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I've already found out what CanExecute method is used for, the thing is, this method is only called when CanExecuteChanged event is fired. Which is where I'm having trouble. I need to fire that event on multiple commands after one of the commands is executed. I know the is a CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested method, but it is a bit too slow, probably because it re-queries all commands (and there are quite a few of them).